# Using WiFi Direct on Samsung Galaxy S II on Gingerbread

Tags: android, galaxy, wifi

Is ther a way to use WiFi Direct on Samsung Galaxy S II on yor App,

calling some sort of API's or anything?

Beacuse the feature does work on these mobiles...
   There's must be a way...

Answer (score 0):

WiFi Direct is an ICS feature and must be supported by the hardware. You will have to wait for the Galaxy SII to get ICS. Even then, I am not sure if the hardware supports it (for example, Nexus S on ICS does not support it).

Comment: Galaxy S II has WiFi Direct. you can use it. Samsunng developed it i guess.

Of course i could wait to ICS on SGS2, it will work for sure. 

But i need it now...
Any knowlege of the Samsung secret API that they've enabled to get thier device to use WiFiDirect?